# Is it possible to encrypt pdf which is signed pdf with digital signature certificate?

Tags: java, pdf, certificate

I have a function to encrypt pdf:

```
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.encryption.AccessPermission;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.encryption.StandardProtectionPolicy;

public String encrypt(String base64File, String password) {
    
        byte[] file = Base64.getDecoder().decode(base64File.getBytes());

        PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(file);

        StandardProtectionPolicy spp = new StandardProtectionPolicy(password, password, new AccessPermission());

        document.protect(spp);

        var byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        document.save(byteArrayOutputStream);

        document.close();

        return new String(Base64.getEncoder().encode(byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray())); 
    }
```

The problem: when pdf that is a pdf with digital signature certificate is passed to the function after encryption the content is fine but the certificate is incorrect. Is it possible to have correct cert after encryption?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The problem: when pdf that is a pdf with digital signature certificate is passed to the function after encryption the content is fine but the certificate is incorrect. Is it possible to have correct cert after encryption?

A digital signature contains a protected hash value of the bytes of the PDF (See [this answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/35131/16096) for details).

[image: Signature hash value computed for these bytes]

If you encrypt the PDF you change these bytes.

Thus, the protected hash value in the signature does not match the PDF bytes anymore. So the signature is broken.

And no, there is no way to correct this (with resources within reason), otherwise the signature would be worthless.

As K J mentioned in his comment, the PDF has to be encrypted already when it is being signed.